# bash scripting - using sed or awk to split and extract data

Tags: regex, awk, sed, dns

I'm having trouble with a specific situation. If I have a file filled with entries like:

```
my.site.example.com
somelinewithnodot
some.line .with.a.weird.space..this.is
this.one.has , and.stuff*.all.I
&&&83%23^&4,I;dont,even.need.2see
```

Using bash, how can I use like awk or sed or something to split the data on each line by "." and then only print the entries directly before and directly after the **last** ".", ignoring lines with no "."?

Desired output:

```
example.com
somelinewithnodot
this.is
all.I
need.2see
```

I've been trying to use sed but I'm having trouble setting up the regex.  I've done stuff like this before but it's been a minute and I'm having trouble remembering how to properly set it up...

Comment: Why not just grep? `grep -Eo '([^.]+\.)?[^.]+$'`

Comment: It is always advisable to add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in your post, kindly do so @Jon Red

Comment: @oguzismail I was having a hard time setting up the regex, it's been a minute since I did this. I wound up using awk instead, though, since it proved to be a simpler solution to this particular puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'.' 'NF>1{print $(NF-1) FS $NF;next} 1'  Input_file
OR
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}NF>1{print $(NF-1) FS $NF;next} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -F'.' 'NF>1{$0=$(NF-1) FS $NF} 1'  Input_file
OR
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}NF>1{print $(NF-1) FS $NF;next} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: I was getting lost trying to use sed and regex when this right here is what I really needed.  This is perfect, thank you so much...

Comment: @JonRed, glad that it helped you, give it sometime and when you see some answers try to select as correct answer out of all, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substitution with sed:

```
sed 's/^\([^.]*\.\)*\([^.]\+\.[^.]\+\)$/\2/'
```

Comment: This is what I was having a hard time trying to build.  I wound up using awk since it was simpler for my example but this was what I was initially attempting.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/.*[.](.*[.].*)$/\1/' file
```

Match the last two `.`'s and replace them by the last `.` and words either side.

Alternative:

```
sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)$/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl also

```
perl -ne ' /(^[^\.]+$)|(?<=\.)([^\.]+\.[^\.]+$)/g and print "$1$2" '
```

with Inputs

```
$ cat johnred.txt
my.site.example.com
somelinewithnodot
some.line .with.a.weird.space..this.is
this.one.has , and.stuff*.all.I
&&&83%23^&4,I;dont,even.need.2see

$ perl -ne ' /(^[^\.]+$)|(?<=\.)([^\.]+\.[^\.]+$)/g and print "$1$2" ' johnred.txt
example.com
somelinewithnodot
this.is
all.I
need.2see

$
```

`.` loses its special meaning when used in [ ], so you can use

```
perl -ne ' /(^[^.]+$)|(?<=\.)([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/g and print "$1$2" ' johnred.txt
```

Another solution using array operation

```
perl -lne ' @b=$_=~/([^.]+)/g ; print $b[-2]? "$b[-2].":"", $b[-1] ' johnred.txt
```